# RegExp not matching for array of patterns

Tags: php, regex

I need to make checking "If not matching".
Is match working correct:

```
<?php
   $string1 = 'BB123';
   $string2 = 'ZZ123';

   $pattern = '/^(AA.*|BB.*|CC.*)$/';

   echo preg_match($pattern, $string1);
   echo preg_match($pattern, $string2);
```

I receiving 1 and 0 and this is okay.
But if changing pattern to

```
$pattern = '/^(?!AA.*|BB.*|CC.*)$/';
```

I'm receiving 00.

Help me to receive 0 and 1 by changing only the pattern.

Comment: why don't you use `echo !preg_match($pattern, $string1);` reverse of output

Comment: Cuz I need to put patterns into out file, depends on rule "contains" or "except".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ^(?!AA.*|BB.*|CC.*).*$
```

Use this.If negative lookahead fails,then accept the string by .*.

Comment: This works, I've forgot for the `.*` at the end. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can also remove redundant `.*` in pattern like that `^(?!AA|BB|CC).*$`

Comment: No, because, sometimes I need to use any characters (`.*`), but sometimes I need to check complete string. Any way, thanks, have modified regexp to `^(?!AA.*$|BB.*$|CC.*$).*$`

Comment: The task is to comvert string rules into regexp patterns like rule: "AB1234, BC*, DE3333" to regexp with modifier "contains" or "except"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<?php
    $string1 = 'BB123';
   $string2 = 'ZZ123';

   $regexp = "(AA.*)|(BB.*)|(CC.*)"; 

   $pattern = "/^((?!(".$regexp.")).)*$/";

   echo preg_match($pattern, $string1);
   echo preg_match($pattern, $string2);
   ?>
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/178050)**

Comment: `$string1 = 'HHBB123';`
`$string2 = 'HHZZ123'` regexp fails